# How can I force refresh of the entire local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating a shopping cart.
Basically, when I reload the page with the products in my cart, the local storage doesn't refresh, which is what I want.

But I also want it to refresh at some point only (when I open another page). How do I get the local storage to refresh completly?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? And show us your code...

Comment: `window.localStorage.clear();`

Comment: I guess local-Storage automatically gets refreshed after refreshing the page if you don't put some if else conditions, remove those if you have some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**localStorage.clear()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear)

The clear() method of the Storage interface clears all keys stored in a given Storage object.

for example

```
//feeds storage
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
localStorage.setItem('john', 'wick');
localStorage.setItem('joe', 'doe');

//lets get the value bar from the localStorage
console.log(localStorage.getItem('foo'))//outputs 'bar'

//clears all data
localStorage.clear();

//now if you try to do it again after you clear it will print null
console.log(localStorage.getItem('foo'))//outputs null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage if you want to delete data anytime user closes the tab, localStorage does not refresh on page refresh or anything like that, what you have to do is use setItem on same key you were using before and pass new or updated data(data you want to change)

```
localStorage.setItem("same-object-key-you-have-used-before",data);
```

by doing this data(updated one) will be stored in localStorage